# Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST Error when the same series of nest and elastic search used

Tags: response, integration, nest, elasticsearch-5

I want to configure elastic client (NEST V7.17.5) on .net core.The version of elastic search used is V7.11.2.
I configured the elastic search connection settings using the code below
`[Extension class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBNY8.png)`
I added the service in startup using the code below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCZ48.png)
Now on trying to search a user using elastic search am getting an error
`Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful () low level call on POST: /users/_search?pretty=true&typed_keys=true

## Audit trail of this API call:

- [1] ProductCheckOnStartup: Took: 00:00:00.0541697
- [2] ProductCheckFailure: Node: https://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.0533032

## OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch due to an unsuccessful product check call. Some functionality may not be compatible if the server is running an unsupported product. Call: Status code unknown from: GET /?pretty=true

---> Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch due to an unsuccessful product check call. Some functionality may not be compatible if the server is running an unsupported product.
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.RequestAsync[TResponse](RequestData requestData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.ThrowIfTransientProductCheckFailure()
at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.PingAsync(Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.PingAsync(IRequestPipeline pipeline, Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.RequestAsync[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, CancellationToken cancellationToken, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

## Request:

<Request stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>

## Response:

<Response stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>
`

Though i came across the same question in stackoverflow i couldn't find a solution . can someone please help with this issue.i am just a beginner in elastic search so please share if someone is familiar with this issue.